# How can you direct a user to add their twitter account to twitter settings using Twitter.framework?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, twitter, ios5

On iOS5 is it possible to prompt and direct a user to the Twitter Settings.app area so they can add their twitter account to the phone?  If so how do you do it?

As a work around I can direct them to open Settings.app but thats about it.

Comment: Turns out somebody else figured out how to do it:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843317/open-twitter-settings-in-settings-app/7956610#7956610

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution in another SO Post:

[Open Twitter settings in Settings app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843317/open-twitter-settings-in-settings-app/7956610#7956610)

Short answer is:

> [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];

Comment: This no longer works in iOS 5.1 and later.  This was an undocumented API and Apple has disabled this capability.

Comment: I recently figured out another way that works in 5.1 - http://goto11.net/programmatically-open-twitter-settings-on-ios-5-1/

Answer (score 2):

I just pop a browser if they don't have the twitter account on the device on an app where the budget was not large enough to implement more complex functionality, this may be useful to some people:

```
if([TWTweetComposeViewController canSendTweet]){ 

   ...

}else{
    NSString *tweet = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://twitter.com/intent/tweet?source=SourceApp&text=%@", [tweetText substringToIndex:140]]; 
    tweet = [tweet stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *webLink = [NSURL URLWithString:tweet];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:webLink];

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tweetsheet did this by itself if tweetsheet found that if there is no account in twitter under setting then it pops an AlertView that will automatically guide user to log in on the native setting for twitter for more refer to this link http://dl.dropbox.com/u/47726728/tweet%20sheet.swf 
download this file and open it in jing or drag it on your browser

Comment: for that you need to go through the api docs or the tutorials provided by the Apple itself and instead for launching the settings you can also make user to login from your app by using Accounts framework provided by apple for more help go to the apple's tutorial videos if like the answer kindly accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

As noted in a comment here, this is now default behavior in iOS since 5.1. Just open one of those widgets and if the user hasn't input an account into iOS the user will be prompted to do so.