# Open Twitter settings in Settings app

Tags: iphone, twitter, settings, ios5

I know I can open the settings app in iOS 5 using

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs://"]];
```

but is there a way to open the Twitter settings page directly?  The desired functionality can be seen when you try to present a TWTweetComposeViewController and you have not set up a Twitter account.

Comment: A very extensive list: http://iphoneza.co.za/IconSettings/

Comment: https://github.com/Burnsoft/Settings-Swipe I recently open sourced the original version of my latest app, as the features will likely never make it on the appstore. It uses local notifications to allow easy access to your iOS5 settings. Including Twitter.

Comment: I recently came up with a way to send a user to Twitter Settings that works in iOS 5.1+ http://goto11.net/programmatically-open-twitter-settings-on-ios-5-1/

Comment: To get this to work in iOS 6, check out the answer I posted here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11325266/open-twitter-setting-from-acaccountstore-ios-5-1-twitter/13293846#13293846

Comment: Using Twitter Framework it may helps you :

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946062/twitter-framework-for-ios6-how-to-login-through-settings-from-app

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Try,

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=TWITTER"]];
```

Comment: Awesome. I was really hoping "prefs:root=LocationServices" would work... but alas :(

Comment: Any idea on getting this to work for third party app settings? I tried using my app's bundle display name and it didn't work. EDIT: it works! It is case sensitive.

Comment: has anyone had experience of recent app rejections for using the twitter pref url? as these are private api calls, I expect that even though directing a user to add a twitter account would still get rejected? (although any common sense person could see that directing user to settings is the right thing to do)

Comment: @Nik I have this in production apps, none were rejected

Comment: interesting. I've had clear indication from app review that any use of prefs URL scheme will be rejected. Have you tried to an update recently? cheers Nik

Comment: @cirrostratus is 5.1 breaking prefs causing your users problems?

Answer (score 4):

I found out that the *root* value is the key of the localized string found in the "Settings.strings" file of the Preferences.app. Here are some values that I tested to work:

General: General
iCloud: CASTLE
Mail: ACCOUNT_SETTINGS
Twitter: TWITTER
Safari: Safari
Music: MUSIC
Video: VIDEO
Photos: Photos
Notes: NOTES
Store: STORE

However I can't figure out how to do this with my own app's settings.
 **prefs:root=Apps&path=<CFBundleDisplayName>** seems not to work.

Answer (score 3):

@Sahil

Use

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=LOCATION_SERVICES"]];
```

to open straight to Location Services

Answer (score 2):

The awesome answers are already given but here is the complete snippet to open twitter settings in Settings using `UIAlertController` and *Swift 3* :

```
 let alert = UIAlertController(title: "No Twitter Accounts", message: "There are no Twitter accounts configured. You can add or create a Twitter account in Settings.", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let firstAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

        })
        let secondAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Settings", style: .default, handler: {(action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in

            let url = URL(string:"App-Prefs:root=TWITTER")!
            if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                UIApplication.shared.open(url, options: [:], completionHandler: nil)
            } else {
                UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
            }
        })
        alert.addAction(firstAction)
        alert.addAction(secondAction)
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just show the composer. If no Twitter Account is available, it will show an AlertView to go to Settings

```
var controller = SLComposeViewController(forServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter)
controller.setInitialText("My Post")
self.presentViewController(controller, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the `prefs:root` scheme is not recommended.  It will very likely be a breaking change with iOS update on the device and could lead to your app being rejected from the app store.

https://gist.github.com/phynet/471089a51b8f940f0fb4