# Twitter Framework for ios6 how to login through settings from app

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter, ios6, social-networking

For iOS5 we can refer :
[Prompt login alert with Twitter framework in iOS5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9667921/prompt-login-alert-with-twitter-framework-in-ios5)

But for iOS6 that will not helpfull i have tried in following way but there is 1 keyboard appearance issue is present is there any one who can help me on this :

```
SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];
tweetSheet.view.hidden=TRUE;

[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:YES completion:^{
    [tweetSheet.view endEditing:YES];
}];
```

Comment: This will shows alert for login only when you have not any twitter account setup on your device.

Comment: For iOS 7, you have to add Twitter, Social, Accounts framework and need to go through these links now dev.twitter.com/docs/ios/using-reverse-auth ... dev.twitter.com/docs/auth/authorizing-request .. Sign in in twitter and add your app in apps.twitter.com

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have make one small change and the issue gone away

in above code when presenting viewcontroller just set `animated:NO`

```
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
        [tweetSheet.view endEditing:YES];
    }]
```

Comment: Nice solution, cant believe there isn't a native check