# Want to redirect to setting page of Facebook if no account is configured in iPhone's Settings app

Tags: facebook, ios6

I'm integrating Facebook to my app for uploading a video to FB. Everything is working fine.

```c
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierFacebook];
        __block ACAccount *facebookAccount;
        NSDictionary *options = @{
                                  ACFacebookAppIdKey: @"457887770928321",
                                  ACFacebookPermissionsKey: @[@"publish_stream", @"publish_actions"],
                                  ACFacebookAudienceKey: ACFacebookAudienceFriends
                                  };
        [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:options completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
            if(granted) {
                NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];
                if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {
                    facebookAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                    NSURL *videourl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://graph.facebook.com/me/videos"];
                    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"thaiPhuketKaronBeach" ofType:@"MOV"];
                    NSURL *pathURL = [[NSURL alloc]initFileURLWithPath:filePath isDirectory:NO];
                    NSData *videoData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:filePath];


                    NSDictionary *params = @{
                                             @"title": @"A video post",
                                             @"description": @"Me testing the video upload to Facebook."
                                             };



                    SLRequest *uploadRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
                                                                  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST
                                                                            URL:videourl
                                                                     parameters:params];
                    [uploadRequest addMultipartData:videoData
                                           withName:@"source"
                                               type:@"video/quicktime"
                                           filename:[pathURL absoluteString]];





                    uploadRequest.account = facebookAccount;
                    NSLog(@"Uploading...");

                    [uploadRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                        NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
                        if(error){
                            NSLog(@"Error %@", error.localizedDescription);
                        }else
                            NSLog(@"Success : %@", responseString);
                    }];


                }
                else{
                      // I want to redirect from here to settings app
                    }
            }
        }];
```

How can I redirect to Settings app to configure FB login if `accountsArray count == 0`?

Comment: Your post helped me to solve uploading video in fb. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is no API for taking the user directly to the FB/TW settings page.

However, the `SLComposeViewController` will prompt the user with an alert if there is no account configured for the set service type (FB/TW/SW).  That alert has an option that takes the user to the FB/TW settings screen.

So, if you detect that there are no accounts configured (SLComposeViewController also has a method for this) then you can present the SLComposeViweController knowing that it will prompt the user with an option to go to settings.

It's not ideal.  The SLComposeViewController still shows behind the alert, and the keyboard appears also.  It's somewhat possible to hide these (controller.view.hidden = YES prior to presenting, etc.), but at the risk that it isn't the expected behavior for this component.

Answer (score 0):

This might help ::

```
        if (error.code == ACErrorAccountNotFound) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                SLComposeViewController *controller = [SLComposeViewController composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook];
                controller.view.hidden = YES;
                [self presentViewController:controller animated:NO completion:^{
                    [controller.view endEditing:YES];
                }];
            });
        }
```

Also see this post :
[Twitter Framework for ios6 how to login through settings from app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13946062/twitter-framework-for-ios6-how-to-login-through-settings-from-app)