# How to programmatically launch iphone twitter settings page in device from app in ios 8 and ios 7

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

I want to launch twitter account settings page in iphone from the app with ios 7 & 8. I tried and able to launch settings page(not twitter settings page) using below code in ios 8

```
BOOL canOpenSettings = (&UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString != NULL);
    if (canOpenSettings) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
    }
```

Please let me know any other  solutions are their to launch in ios 7 and ios 8 twitter settings page

Comment: look this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7843317/open-twitter-settings-in-settings-app

Comment: it is only for ios 5 not for ios 7 & 8